# Where to put a condition or a message that a record were successfully updated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

This jquery successfully added data to the database but no message was shown afterwards. Any idea on where to insert the message and how? Thanks

```
$(document).on('submit','#updateForm',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $('#updateForm').serializeArray();
      $.post('update_a_record.php',data,function(htmlResponse){
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(htmlResponse);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Open developers console and check for errors.

Comment: your ajax response will be displayed to `#ajaxResponse` which you have declared in any div. And another reason is, you may be not passing any values from your `update_a_record.php` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello Romeo,**

Try this below code,

```
$(document).on('submit','#updateForm',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'update_a_record.php',
       data: $('#updateForm').serialize(),   
       success: function(data){
          //alert(data); 
          $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
       },
       error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
         var msg = '';
         if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
              msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
         } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
             msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
         } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
             msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
         } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
             msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
         } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
         } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
         } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
         }
         $('#ajaxResponse').html(msg);
       }
    });
 });
```

I hope my answer is helpfull. If any query so comment please.

Comment: on my update_a_record.php. I have this " echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$unchanged');</script>"; " and is displaying.

Comment: means that  " echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$unchanged');</script>";  this line retrive from update_a_record.php file yes?

Comment: update_a_record.php in this file only write like echo "successfully insert data." not write "<script>" tag and this record get in 'data' of jquery. And show in your div tag and alert tag.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [`done`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [`fail`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.post('update_a_record.php', data, function(htmlResponse) {
    $('#ajaxResponse').html(htmlResponse);
}).done(function() {
    alert("second success");
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh. I tried your code and its working but after the alert of "The field name is empty, must be filled out". the alert "second success" will follow and empty value is saving on the database.

How would I do it from happening?